# Is there a way to auto update my github repo?

Tags: web, github, cloud

I have a website running on cloud server. Can I link the related files to my github repository. So whenever I make any changes to my website, it get auto updated in my github repository?

Comment: Are you saying you want github to get updated as you make changes to your website on your cloud server? Use rsync or something similar that don't require user input to commit changes instead.

Comment: Yes. I want my github to get auto-updated without any user input to commit changes

Comment: How can I use rsync? Is there any alternative tool provided by GitHub?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have your cloud server running an OS that support bash script, add this file to your repository.

Let's say your files are located in `/home/username/server` and we name the file below `/home/username/server/AUTOUPDATE`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cd $(dirname ${BASH_SOURCE[0]})

if [[ -n $(git status -s) ]]; then
    echo "Changes found. Pushing changes..."
    git add -A && git commit -m 'update' && git push
else
    echo "No changes found. Skip pushing."
fi
```

Then, add a scheduled task like crontab to run this script as frequent as you want your github to be updated. It will check if there is any changes first and only commit and push all changes if there is any changes.

This will run every the script every second.

```
*/60 * * * * /home/username/server/AUTOUPDATE
```

Don't forget to give this file execute permission with `chmod +x /home/username/server/AUTOUPDATE`

This will always push the changes with the commit message of "*update*".

Comment: Thank you!! I guess in the solution you mentioned, there would be multiple commits even if I changed a single word.

Comment: @KillMe That is right. This is why I recommended something else like rsync that's not using git. Git just doesn't work the way you want it to be.

Comment: So what would be a more efficient solution? How does rsync works? How does it know when to start commit or update my github repo?

Comment: @KillMe I'm assuming you want the codes on the server copied elsewhere so it's accessible without accessing the server. Sadly, it will not work with github. You need your own server or find some other service that support rsync which works similar to something like dropbox. Something similar works too but that's not the scope of this question.

Comment: Is there a module/package for Node.js to achive the goal of such autoupdating?